# viewport meta tag doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want that my site [uoga.onclick.lt](http://uoga.onclick.lt) in mobile devices would be zoomed out to fit all content.

My tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I tried lots of changes like changing initial-scale and other option changes, but it's still loads like this:

[image]

Device is SONY Xperia Z2, but i tried with Samsung NOTE 2 and nexus 5, the results are the same...

Comment: Try adding also maximum-scale. This tag works for me everytime :)

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">

Comment: https://edwin-europe.com/ has this line <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> and works fine :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fZAnScc.png works for me.. but you have a horizontal-scroller cause of those caption-textthingies.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A zoomed out effect?

Comment: My site has no responsive so i want that in mobile devices it would fit in screen, not be zoomed like it's now

Comment: Just adding the viewport meta doesn't make a site responsive...there's a lot more to it than that....It's not a *magic wand*.

Comment: I know what's responsive means, i made some responsive design projects and i also know that this is just a tag to zoom out a site that he would fit in screen, i think you miss understood me :)

Comment: then you could've just completely dismissed the meta-tag cause then it will automatically zoom into the viewport on mobile devices. but it will look messy then.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=0.2">
```

Tested on Sony Z2, Samsung Note 2, Samsung galaxy s5, Nexus 5.

I really don't know why content="width=device-width" didn't worked...

If you want to see the result, i changed server - uogauoga.itgirnos.lt

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just noticed if you set the width which is larger than your screen for body or html element, the viewport won't work as expected.

e.g.

```
body
{
     width:1080px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this issue and I have similar problem as @Charlie but different solution. In my case I had `pre` tags that had long lines, so in fact the width of the body was large (hence similarities):

the fix:

```
<style>
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>
```